# Does Git create a branch when merging?

Tags: git

Suppose two users are working on the same branch (e.g. `master`). I know this premise is not good practice, but let's use it for simplicity's sake.

The first user runs these commands:

```
git clone <repository_url>
cd myproject
touch file1.cpp
git add file1.cpp
git commit -m "file 1 creation"
```

The second user then runs:

```
git clone <repository_url>
cd myproject
touch file2.cpp
git add file2.cpp
git commit -m "file 2 creation"
```

First user:

```
git push origin master
```

Second user:

```
git pull
```

Now, Git is performing a merge.

At this point, I sometimes see `master|MERGING` in my bash prompt (i.e. before $) so Git  automatically created a branch for merging. In other instances, Git does not create a new branch, because my bash prompt still says `master`.

If it helps, I am working in different operating systems (Linux, Mac, Windows).

So does Git create a branch when merging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reveals a lot of confusing about what a Git branch is and how merges work in Git.  (This is not all that surprising since a lot of introductions to Git are ... not good, and Git has a lot of underlying complexity that really cannot be ignored.)

I recommend that anyone new to Git *avoid* `git pull`.  Instead, run `git fetch`, and then if you *want* merges, run `git merge`.  If you prefer a rebase-oriented work flow, run `git fetch`, then run `git rebase`.  This will give you a better sense of what's going on underneath.  It will also avoid a lot of mistakes that people almost always make as they first start using Git.  **The opposite of push is fetch,** not pull.

You mention that:

> Sometimes ... I see `master|MERGING` in my bash prompt prefix

You can also run `git status` to see whether you are in the middle of a conflicted merge.

In fact, what you have in your bash prompt is a set of clever interactions between your bash shell and your Git commands, where your bash checks with Git each time it's about to print a prompt.  If Git reports that you are in a repository at all, the shell includes the repository's current-branch-name in the prompt.  If you are in the middle of one of these conflicted merges, you get `|MERGING` added as well.

But this leads back to the question: [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Click on that question to read more.  The word *branch* can refer to either a *branch name* like `master`, or a *subgraph within the DAG* (what I like to call a *DAGlet;* see that other question).

The `git merge` command *does not* create a new *name*, so in this sense, it never creates a branch.

On the other hand, the `git merge` command *can* tie together two subgraphs within the DAG—creating a new DAGlet.  In this sense, it does create a new branch.  Well, it does so *sometimes*, and it would be more accurate to say that it *ties together* some *existing* DAGlets.  This is where that unavoidable complexity comes in.

#### Let's take a moment to examine commits

Probably the most important thing in Git is the commit.  In Git, the true name of any commit is its hash ID—some big ugly string of hexadecimal digits, apparently random, basically useless to humans, but each string is unique to that particular commit and identifies it.  That's how *Git* finds it: you tell it to look for some big ugly hash, `a1f9c32...` or whatever, and your Git looks up the commit.

Each commit stores the ID of its *previous* or *parent* commit.  What this means is that if you tell Git about the *latest* commit, Git can use that commit to look back to the second-latest commit.  That second-latest commit has inside it the ID of the third-latest commit, and so on.  If the commit IDs were just easy uppercase letters, we could draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the latest, and it *points to* (contains the ID of) `G`, which points to `F`, and so on, backwards through history.

These commits *are* the history; all Git needs to know is *which one is the latest*.  That's where a branch name like `master` comes in: instead of making you memorize the crazy hash IDs, Git stores the *latest* one under a name like `master`.

This means that when you add a *new* commit to your `master`, what you are doing is having Git save, in a new commit, the ID of the old tip of the chain, and then having your Git rewrite your `master` to hold the ID of the new tip:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Now `I` points back to `H`, which (still) points back to `G`, and so on.

#### There is more than one Git repository involved

You start with this:

> Let's suppose I have 2 users working on the same branch (`master`).

Regardless of whether this is good practice or not, there's a sense here that the name, `master`, means only one thing.  But that's just not true, because *you* have a Git repository, and the *second user* has a Git repository, and the place you're `git push`ing to has a Git repository.  [*Everyone gets a <strike>car</strike> <strike>upvote</strike> <strike>meme</strike> repository!*](https://www.livememe.com/jcrv2w1)  And every one of you has *your own* master.

What you all *share*, however, are some set of *commits*.  You all started out by cloning some repository, and that had some set of commits, and you got them all.  You may have added some more since then.  So, for each commit hash ID, your Git repository either *has* that commit, indicated by its ID, or doesn't.  If your Git repository *doesn't* have that commit, that's where `git fetch` and `git push` come in.

What `git fetch` and `git push` do is to *connect two Git repositories*.  At this point, whoever is doing the sending—your Git if you are the one doing `git push`, or the *other* Git repository if you are doing `git fetch`—packages up any commits *they* have that *you* don't, or vice versa.  The sender delivers that pack of commits (and the files that go with it) to the receiver.

The receiver now has a bit of a problem, because commits that are only identified by hash IDs are pretty useless to humans.  The receiver needs to give the *last* commit a *name*.

When you run `git fetch origin`,<sup>1</sup> you obtain new commits from *their* `master`, so the name *your* Git uses to remember *their* `master` is `origin/master`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, `origin` is the name of a *remote*.  Most repositories have exactly one remote, named `origin`: when you run `git clone <url>` to clone a repository, the clone process sets up this remote, whose name defaults to `origin`, to remember the URL.

---

#### Fetching, then merging

Let's suppose that you both started with a chain of commits ending at `H`, and you've added `I--J` and they—whoever *they* is here—added `K--L`:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- origin/master
```

It's now *your* job to *combine* your work—whatever you did in commits `I-J`—with *their* work, whatever they did in `K-L`.

The simplest method of combining in Git is `git merge`.  This particular *kind* of merge, which I like to call a *true merge*, works by quite literally combining your work and their work.  To do this, it has to start from the point where you two branched apart.  **Note that this branching-apart has nothing to do with the name `master` itself.  It's because *you* made commits, and *they* made commits.**

The merge operation has two parts.  The first is what I like to call *merge as a verb*, or *to merge:* to combine work.  Now, it's clear from looking at the drawing above that the last commit you both had in common was commit `H`.  This is what Git calls the *merge base*.

Git now runs `git diff` twice.<sup>2</sup>  You can do it yourself:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J> > /tmp/what-we-did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L> > /tmp/what-they-did
```

You can now compare what you did to what they did.  Git does this same thing in order to combine your changes with their changes.

If the things you changed are "far enough away from" the things *they* changed, or are in different files, Git will combine them successfully.  More precisely, Git will *think* it combined them successfully.  (It's up to you, the human who is smarter than Git, to decide on the real success here.)  But if you changed the *same source lines* that they changed, Git won't be able to combine two different changes.  Git will throw its metaphoric hands into the air, declare a *merge conflict*, and stop and make *you* clean up the mess.

**This is when you see the merging status.**  Git has stopped *in the middle* of a conflicted merge.  The *commit graph* still looks like the picture above, with two "branches" (in the DAGlet sense) forking off from a common commit; they have not yet come together.  It's now your job to edit the mess into something sensible, run `git add` on the result, and use `git commit` (or in new enough Git versions, `git merge --continue`—but this just runs `git commit`) to finish the merge.

If Git thinks it can do the merge all on its own, though, `git merge` will go ahead and run `git commit` on its own too.  Git *won't* stop in the middle with a conflict; it will just go on to the `git commit` part.

This commit-that-concludes-a-merge, whether Git does it all by itself or stops and makes you clean up and do it, will *tie together* the two graph DAGlets:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J--M   <-- master
            \      /
             K----L   <-- origin/master
```

The new merge commit `M` has *two* parents, instead of just the usual one.  **This is the second part of what `git merge` does: it creates a *merge commit***, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective.  The merge commit ties together these two DAGlets.  **Merging did not create the graph fragments.  Merging simply tied them together.**

Making this merge commit concludes the process of merging, so that you are now back to the normal, non-merging state.  However, you now have a new commit that, obviously, no one else has: you have merge commit `M`, which you just made, which therefore has a new and unique hash ID that no one else could possibly have yet.

(You can now use `git push` to share any commits that you have that they don't.)

---

<sup>2</sup>Internally, Git uses a whole bunch of short-cuts to avoid a lot of work if possible, but in the end, the *combine* part does require computing the diff.

I'm also leaving out a lot of detail here about how the *to merge* process works.  This matters mainly when you have to clean up the mess of a failed merge: the merge takes place in your *index* (also called your *staging area*) as well as in your *work-tree* (where you do your work).  The separations between commits, the index, and the work-tree matter more as you start to do more advanced things in Git.

---

#### When a merge isn't a merge

Not all `git merge` operations merge!  Suppose you *haven't* done any work since you ran `git clone`, so that you have, say:

```
...--F   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now you run `git fetch` and pick up new commits `G` and `H`:

```
...--F   <-- master
      \
       G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Note that `G` points back to `F`, which is where you are now.  If you now run `git merge origin/master` (or just `git merge`) to bring yourself forward, Git notices that there is no actual *divergence* here.  Instead of combining your lack-of-work with their work, Git can simply *fast-forward* the name `master` so that it points to commit `H`, and check out commit `H`, giving you:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

When `git merge` does this, it says "fast-forward": there's no diffing, no combining of work, and no new merge commit.  This process is very easy for Git, compared to a true merge: in the end, it's essentially the same amount of work as `git checkout`.

#### You can rebase instead of merging

I won't go into great detail here, but instead of *merging* your work with someone else's work, you can *rebase* your work *on* someone else's work.  Suppose we start with the same work-that-needs-combining diagram:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- origin/master
```

Instead of merging, we can have Git *copy* commits `I` and `J` to *new, somewhat different* commits which we can call `I'` and `J'` to remind us that they're a lot like `I` and `J`, but not the same.  (They'll have new, unique hash IDs, different from your original `I` and `J`.)  We simply arrange them like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- origin/master
                 \
                  I'-J'  <-- ???
```

Now that we have these copies made, we have our Git "peel the label" `master` off `J` and make it point to `J'` instead:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- ???
            \
             K--L   <-- origin/master
                 \
                  I'-J'  <-- master
```

If you now choose to *give up* the originals, since you don't need them any more, we can remove the question-mark labels entirely and straighten out one of the kinks in the graph:

```
...--F--G--H--K--L   <-- origin/master
                  \
                   I'-J'  <-- master
```

Now it seems as though you wrote your two commits *after* picking up commit `L`, instead of writing them based on commit `H`.  The source code that is carried with the two new commits `I'` and `J'` is based on what's in `L`, rather than what's in `H`.

If you would have gotten merge conflicts when merging, you will almost certainly get merge conflicts when rebasing—and you *may* get many repeated conflicts (depending on how many commits you made), and they *may* be harder to resolve than they would be with merging.  But in the end, you avoid the merge commit itself, and when you go to look at the history of all development, it will *seem* simpler, even if it was actually more complicated.

Whether to do this is up to you.  If you do choose to do it, though, you do it *instead of* merging.  Remember that rebase works by *copying* some set of commits; be careful to copy only those commits that you have not already published (with `git push`), or to be sure that anyone else who had the originals switches away from the originals to the new improved copies.

#### One final note on `git push`

We've seen above that fetch (not pull) is the opposite of push.  But there is still one more bit of asymmetry.  When you run `git push`, you have your Git hand over your commits to some other Git repository.  This all works by hash IDs, just like fetch works by hash IDs—and at the end, just like fetch had to set a name in *your* repository to remember *their* latest `master`, `push` has to set a name in *their* repository to remember *your* last commit.

But—here's the asymmetry—your Git asks their Git to set *their* `master`.  It's not their `bob/master`, it's their `master`.  As a general rule, their Git will *refuse to allow this operation unless it's a fast-forward.*

This fast-forward is the same kind of thing we saw with a fast-forward not-really-a-merge `git merge`.  It means that we are only *adding commits to* some branch name: the new commit(s) eventually point back to the commits they already had.  That's what you are doing when you run `git merge` or `git rebase`: you combine your work with their latest, so that your work *adds on to* theirs, rather than erasing some of theirs.

In the end, Git is all about the *commits*, but the names—the branch names like `master`, or your remote-tracking names like `origin/master`—are all about *finding the commits*.  The names are both for humans (who can't deal with raw hash IDs) *and* for locating the *tip-most* commit on a branch.  That tip commit points backwards, in the same way that Git always works backwards, to earlier commits, and by doing so, it keeps those earlier commits alive.  The name keeps the tip commit alive and the tip commit keeps earlier commits, and that's why `git push` demands that the push be a fast-forward.

(You can do non-fast-forward pushes using `git push --force` or equivalent.  This has the effect of killing off some commit in the Git that receives the force-push.  If you want to kill them off, that's OK—but other Git users may have `fetch`ed those commits, so beware: they could come back!)

Comment: Clear and thorough write-up, torek! Wish I had that to refer to way back when I was learning git!

Answer (score 1):

Doing `git pull` is the same as doing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  At the end of the second user's merge, Git will create a new merge *commit*, but it won't, by itself, create a new branch.

The `master|MERGING` you see on the console just means that Git is in the middle of a merge operation.

Comment: @Bob5421 It just means you are in the middle of an unfinished merge.  You may try running `git branch -a` when you see this.  My guess is that you won't see any new branches.  If Git does create a temporary branch, it is not visible to us.

Comment: Thanks all, but how can i see if i am in merging status if i do not see | MERGING in the console ?

Comment: @Bob5421 That strikes me as something of a circular question.  If you do a merge and you _don't_ see `MERGING`, then it usually means that Git was able to complete the merge without input from you.

Answer (score 0):

In the steps you describe, `git pull` merges remote branch (`origin/master`) into a local `master` branch. And as Tim's answer suggests, it creates a merge commit on your local `master` branch.

To answer your question: both branches are created during the `git clone` operation. `git fetch` updates the state of `origin/master` in the local repository (to the current state on the server).

Answer (score 0):

It won't create a new branch. The 2nd user (any user for instance) would have a local copy of master. By running git pull the remote changes are `fetched` and `merged`. Merge would fail if there are conflicting changes.

Best way to handle is, for the 2nd user to do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

This would pull the remote changes and apply them on top of his local commit and then can be pushed to remote Master.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, git is creating So called "**merge commit".**

If you would like to avoid this you should go with `git pull --rebase` each time you pull. This way git will do marge "while pulling" **and skip creating "marge commit"** .

But you should remember that `rebase`option forces you to handle potential conflicts.

Comment: `This way git will do marge "while pulling"` -> No. Git *always* do merge while pulling, because `pull` is the same as `fetch` + `merge`. The `--rebase` option tells it to _rebase_ instead of merging.

Comment: One more thing: When i do a git fetch, how can i see fetched files ? I just see my current files...

Comment: @Bob5421 Again, this question seems a bit off kilter to me.  When you `git fetch`, you are telling Git to return the latest version of _every_ file.  Perhaps you want to know which _new_ files were added?  I think Git will already tell you this.